# PowerPC ASM: insrdi instruction

Tags: assembly, disassembly, powerpc

The [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_em_6b4brotate_sh.htm) defines this operation as "Insert double word from right immediate", but does not really clarify what it does.

I am trying to understand what the following operation does:

```
insrdi r10, r25, 32, 20  #r25 = 0x817
```

From what I gather, it is taking `0x817` from `r25` and appears to be doing some sort of shift. However, I don't understand what is happening mathematically and would like some clarification.

Comment: It's taking the low 32 bits of r25 and copying it into r10 from bit #20. The formula would be something like `r10 = (r10 & 0xfff00000000fffff) | ((r25 & 0xffffffff) << 20)`

Comment: One tricky thing with PowerPC is that it numbers bits from the *top* of the register (the MSB), not the bottom (LSB) like most other ISAs.  The page you linked is just a summary: IBM does have detailed instruction-set-reference documentation for every instruction.